# Django get_absolute_url in inclusion_tag Issue in Template

Tags: python, django, templatetags

The error I'm getting is:

> ```
> NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'view_page' not found. 'view_page' is
> not a valid view function or pattern name.
> ```

Basically I have a template tag for my app to display the navigation menu on each page, which is dynamic so I can't hard-code the links.  I've written an inclusion tag and template:

```
from django import template
from ..models import Page

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag("tags/page_links.html")
def page_links():
    all_pages = Page.objects.all()
    return {'pages': all_pages}
```

And the template tag html in the templates/tags directory:

```
<ul>
  {% for page in pages %}
  <li><a href="{{ page.get_absolute_url }}">{{ page.link_name }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Each page object has an @permalink get_absolute_url() function to get the link.  This works fine in other parts of the site but this inclusion tag does not.  I'm using it like so in my base.html file (so I don't have to add it to each page):

```
{% load static %}
{% load page_tags %}

...

    <p><b>Navigation:</b></p>
    {% page_links %}

...
```

But it appears that the pages are having trouble using the view_page view (which otherwise works) in the template tag.  What am I missing here?

### EDIT: Added URLs and Model code

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls import url

from .views import index, view_page

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^$', index),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[^\.]+).html', view_page),
]
```

And the Model:

```
class Page(SortableMixin):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=80, unique=True)
    link_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    passthrough_page = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    passthrough_link = models.CharField(max_length=40, default=None, null=True)
    content = models.TextField(default=None, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['the_order']

    the_order = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, editable=False, db_index=True)

    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        if not self.passthrough_page:
            return 'view_page', None, {'slug': self.slug}
        else:
            return self.passthrough_link
```

Comment: You need to show your URLs and the Page `get_absolute_url` method.

Comment: Also, what version of Django are you using? permalink was deprecated in 1.11.

Comment: Thanks for the response - code added above, django version is 2.0.  I'll try adding the reverse to the ```get_absolute_url``` code and see if that fixes things.

Comment: Appears to have been the ```reverse``` vs. ```@permalink``` issue - when I changed it to a ```reverse``` call in the ```get_absolute_url``` function everything's working great.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A change from `@permalink` (which I was informed has been deprecated) to calling `reverse` directly seems to have done the trick:

In the model code:

```
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        if not self.passthrough_page:
            return reverse('view_page', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
        else:
            return self.passthrough_link
```